# advanced socket byte reading for slow connection

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

i just want to ask a mere noob question probably...
if the connection is slow and it's not recommended to read the whole byte at a time...
then what would be the best socket reading algorithm that will work?

since i've experienced couple of times when reading a socket, sometimes the byte stream weren't completely transferred and make it an invalid data...

currently i'm reading my socket like this:

```
byte[] message = new byte[lengthOftheByte];
byte buffer = 0;
int count = 0;
while(count < lengthOftheByte) {
  int read = myInputStream.read();
  buffer = (byte) read;
  message[count] = buffer;
  count++;
}
```

it read single byte then put it into an array's element
it works on single read process but not within a thread... :(

Comment: What do you mean by "but not within a thread"? Your question isn't really clear...

Comment: It made it invalid data because you store the byte read and continue reading from the stream even if the end has been reached. You should always test the result of the read, and stop if it's -1.

Answer (score 1):

Use either `read(byte[])` or a `BufferedInputStream`. However this technique is recommended for all connections, not just slow connections. If you have a slow connection so you are input-bound, nothing you can do to the code can possibly help.